# std::ofstream open file and replace in specific offset

Tags: c++, std, fstream, ofstream

I want to open a file (without re-creating it) and write to a specific offset.
This is the current code :

```
std::ofstream file(conf_file_path, std::ios::app);
file.seekp(offset, std::ios::beg);
const auto& output = file.write(conf_str, conf_str_len);
```

But it always writes to the end of file (probably due to the `app` flag)
If I don't use the `app` flag, it re-creates the file as I open it.

How can I open it without re-create it and be able to write to specific offset ?

Comment: Simply `std::ofstream file(conf_file_path, std::ios::out | std::ios::in);`

Comment: I suggest you check e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open), it has a nice table of the different [open modes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) and what they correspond to for the C function [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) and what the modes do when the file exist and doesn't exist.

Comment: By the way, if the file you open is a text file, do all records (lines etc.) have a fixed size? Because if the data in the file is not of a fixed size, then how will you know the amount to seek? And if you overwrite data, what do you think will happen if you write less than what was there before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it always writes to the end of file (probably due to the app flag)

Yes, this is due to the `app` flag. Here's what the documentation says:

> app - seek to the end of stream before each write

---

> If I don't use the app flag, it re-creates the file as I open it.

If you have `out` or `trunc` flags sets in the mode, then it destroys the contents of the file, if it already exists.

> How can I open it without re-create it and be able to write to specific offset ?

You may use `in|out`. This will error out if the file doesn't exist; if it exists, the file will be opened and read from the beginning. If you want the stream to be read from the end, you may set the `ate` flag additionally.

All of this is clearly documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open); reading the manual really helps.